# Visual studio on linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio

Is there any way i can install visual studio on linux?

Already tried installing it. Rider is too expensive for my needs and I want to upgrade from Window to Linux. Distro: Garuda

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run it natively. Perhaps there's a workaround by using a Windows virtual machine inside your Linux distro and then using Visual Studio in the VM.

A quick google yielded these alternatives that are Linux compatible, but as you can read by the comments under each listing, it depends on your use case. See if any of these will work for you: https://alternativeto.net/software/jetbrains-rider/

Answer (score -3):

Visual Studio Code (interactive text editor) runs pretty fine. Although you will need several extensions for languages like C# to compile. There is also a gtk# language implementation with MonoDevelop (C# native implementation for linux), but its development was freezed.